# How to check only visible items in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I called one API and loaded a list of data in RecyclerView. Now User clicks any one of the item then a new page open. In this new page, I am calling a new API which are able to fetch data. My problem is that if internet speed it too much slow, it takes too much time to be loaded. So i am trying to optimize the performance. **I do not know which logic will be best.**

I am trying one logic. When user scroll to first page ( Recycler view). I will call details page API and preload data and keeps it in locally db (sqlite). So when i clicked on any item, details page will be open and check if locally has data or not. if locally has data, it will display using locally. So i think it should be faster.

So for applying above logic,I will have to call API during only visible items on Recycler view. So i am using **addOnScrollListener** but it calls many times. I just need to call it which items are visible to user. If there are 3 item visible then 1 time it should be call but it is calling many times and api is calling many times.

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                    if (dy < 0) {
                        // Recycle view scrolling up...

                    } else if (dy > 0) {
                        // Recycle view scrolling down...
                        int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                        int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                        int findLastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                        int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                        Log.e("","firstVisiblePosition ="+firstVisiblePosition
                                +"\nfindFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition ="+findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition
                                +"\nfindLastVisibleItemPosition ="+findLastVisibleItemPosition
                                +"\nfindLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition ="+findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition);

                        // here many times it is checking in locally.
                        //check locally has data
                        //if yes
                        //Call API.

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Well, onScrolled is called even if you scroll by a dp, hence, it's getting called many times. One thing you can do is, when you have fetched the list you can start a fetch details & store in db call for each list item, in background. On item click you can check if it's details have been populated in the db.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari yes i was also thinking it. Suppose i have 100 items in list. I worry about locally sizes also. i just want to load which user has visible .

Answer (score 0):

I believe onScrolled might be called too frequently for what you're trying to solve.  Try checking the callback in LayoutManager instead since

> A LayoutManager is responsible for measuring and positioning item views within a RecyclerView as well as determining the policy for when to recycle item views that are no longer visible to the user.

Possibly check if these callbacks will work for you [onItemsAdded](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#onItemsAdded(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20int,%20int)), [onLayoutChildren](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#onLayoutChildren(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Recycler,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)), or onAddFocusables ...I can't post 3 links =(